# Target specific element to replace content in long list of repeating elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm displaying a list of dynamic content on a single page with the same flag and like buttons for each piece of content. I want a user to be able to click a "Like" button and have the "Dislike" button for that entry to be disabled and vice versa.

My problem is this: If a user clicks "Dislike" then ALL the "Like" buttons become disabled on the page. I want just the associated "Like" button for that entry to be affected.

I have this code which partially works but, as I said, it changes all the Like buttons on the page. How do update content for just one of them?

Note: the back-end handling of the functionality of these buttons is working fine and this question is about jquery and bootstrap functionality only. Much thanks.

```
<div class="text-right">
<span class="like"><a class="likelink btn btn-info btn-xs" href="{path='sightings/ajax_like'}/{entry_id}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></span>
<span class="flag"><a class="flaglink btn btn-info btn-xs" href="{path='sightings/ajax_flag'}/{entry_id}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></span>
</div>

<div class="text-right">
<span class="like"><a class="likelink btn btn-info btn-xs" href="{path='sightings/ajax_like'}/{entry_id}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></span>
<span class="flag"><a class="flaglink btn btn-info btn-xs" href="{path='sightings/ajax_flag'}/{entry_id}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></span>
</div>

<div class="text-right">
<span class="like"><a class="likelink btn btn-info btn-xs" href="{path='sightings/ajax_like'}/{entry_id}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></span>
<span class="flag"><a class="flaglink btn btn-info btn-xs" href="{path='sightings/ajax_flag'}/{entry_id}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></span>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){

//  FLAGGING

    $('a.flaglink').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var flaglink = $(this);
        var url = flaglink.attr('href');
        if (url !== null) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function(results) {

                    flaglink.closest('.flag').html('<a href="#" class="flaglink btn btn-xs btn-danger" title="flagged"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></span> Flagged</a>').fadeIn('slow');
                    $('span.like').closest('a.likelink').prop('disabled', true);

                },
                error: function(results) {
                    console.log('ERROR:' + results);
                }
            });
        } // if

    }); //  flag


}); // document ready
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the instance of `flaglink` so use that specific instance to traverse from and not the more generic `$('span.like')` which includes all of that class that exist

Something like:

```
flaglink.parent().siblings('.like').find('a.likelink').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: I tried this answer and it didn't work. The basic idea seems correct to me but even after trying a few permutations it continued to not work.

Comment: Create a live demo in jsfiddle or other sandbox

Comment: I created this jsfiddle but it's not working like the development site because the ajax isn't wired up. Please be patient as this is my first jsfiddle so I'm not sure I've done this correctly. hope this helps, thanks. https://jsfiddle.net/58ep2x7k/7/